# Replace “” in AutoHotkey

Tags: string, replace, autohotkey, double-quotes

This is a weird kind of double quotes that I'm having to deal with from a text file:

[image]

Here's the text the way my clipboard manages it:

```
II=" alt="“”" />][N
```

The point is: I am trying to use `StrReplace()` to detect that string and replace it, but it doesn't find the content that my clipboard gets by copy & paste.

This doesn't find anything to replace by `foo`:

```
fixedContent := StrReplace(myContent, "II="" alt=""“”"" />][N", "foo")
```

It seems that `“”` is not the same as [image].

Maybe I have to use a special character?

Answer (score 1):

The characters `“”` the same as [image], it's just different fonts.

```
myContent = <IT="" alt="“”" />][Nebula]
find = IT="" alt="“”" />][N
replaceWith = foo
fixedContent := StrReplace(myContent, find, replaceWith)
msgbox % fixedContent
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
fixedContent:=StrReplace(myContent, "“”", "foo")
```

Comment: I played with backticks as suggested by `StrReplace()` examples but that doesn't make the job.

Comment: Could you provide the original text string (not image)? Have you already searched for the ascii number of these characters?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ASCII numbers and such things. To include here the original text string I have to copy & paste, and the final result is the same as above: I don't know how to provide you with the original text string without using the clipboard that produces `“”`...

Comment: I corrected my first answer, just use the above line.

Comment: It doesn't work :(
It ignores that `"“”"` as if didn't find it.

Comment: Here is the test I made and it's working: `myContent = alt="“”"
MsgBox %myContent%
fixedContent:=StrReplace(myContent, "“”", "foo")
MsgBox %fixedContent%`

Comment: Also try to update your Autohotkey to the last verion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170097/discussion-between-rogerio-dec-and-lisa-ann).